# Change Position of y axis facet grid ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This my ggplot:

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(cty,hwy))+geom_line()+facet_grid(year~.)
```

How can I change the position of "1998" and "2008" to become the titles of each horizontal plot?

Comment: Does replacing `facet_grid` with `facet_wrap` give what you want?

Comment: @JuliusVainora no. I would like to have the opportunity to change "1998" and "2008" to others texts. So, I would like manage as a title. Also, my original data the `facet_wrap` wouldnt be approriate.

Comment: As Julius Vainora suggested, use facet_wrap then add ncol = 1 as an additional argument. `facet_wrap(year~., ncol = 1)`. Does this help?

Comment: By using `facet_wrap(year~., ncol = 1)` how can I change the titles names, the bankground color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(cty,hwy))
    +geom_line()
    +facet_wrap(~ year, strip.position = "top", ncol = 1)
```

As long as you're able to use facet_wrap.

Comment: thanks. How can I change the names and the background colour?

Comment: Change the background color by adding `+theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="orange"))`
Are you able to change the names in the underlying data?

Comment: Actually, that's unnecessary - you can transform in place:
`ggplot(transform(mpg, year = c("First Year", "Second Year")),aes(cty,hwy)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ year, strip.position = "top", ncol = 1) +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="orange"))`

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves using factor with facet_wrap and relabeling, so you can relabel the titles as you see fit. I also added parameters to theme() that will allow you to manipulate the strip parameters

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(cty,hwy))+geom_line()+
    facet_wrap(~factor(year, labels = c("Other 1", "Other 2")), ncol = 1, scales = "free") + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey60"), ##Manipulates background
        strip.text = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold") ##Manipulates text
    )
```

[image]